# Android - how to start chain of activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I intend to start 3 activities in a chain (like from main open Activities A, B and then C, which will be visible for the user), but I wasn't able to find some way how to do that in Android. Do not ask me why, I just have to do that for restoring my application state, where is was before.

Thanks for any ideas

Waypoint

**Edit:**

Ok, I have tried opening activities in For cycle, but they aren't opened properly. They are chained, but recreated only when I press back button and they display to me. I need some solution which leads to: open A, if A is opened check if needs to open B -> YES, open B, check if needs to open C -> YES, open C, no need to open another activity -> FINISH

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Override the `onResume`-method in each activity. Add the check and the start of the activity there.

```
public void onResume() {
  if( condition )
    startActivity( intentForTheNextActivity );
}
```

Where `condition` is whatever condition you might have (in your example if B should be started, C should be started etc.) and `intentForTheNextActivity` is the intent for the following activity in the chain (e.g. if now in A, the intent is for B etc.).

---

I'm having a very hard time understanding exactly what it is you're trying to do. Sometimes it seems like it's a chain (A opens B, B opens C and so forth) sometimes it seems you want some random flow (A opens B, B opens A, A opens B, B opens C) - which makes it really hard to give you a specific answer.

What I can do, is recommend that you read up on the following:

[Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

[Starting Activities and getting results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) (in particular the methods [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29))

If you need more help than this - you need to explain yourself better (maybe with a diagram or some sample code of what you have tried so far).

Comment: Problem is if I have dynamic classes, which goes one by one (A->B->A->B->A->B) and in your example I am opening from A: B (but not whole, just some quick, then A fully opened and thats all...

Answer (score 0):

prior to start any activity , decide which activity should be start .
Lets take your case >>first check for B , if  yes check for C , now open the required 1 .

i understand comparable data is inside the activities, but a right data structure will always allow you to access the data wherever and whenever it actually requires .

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: if you want to start activity with proper back stack, you should use `TaskStackBuilder`.

1. define the natural hierarchy for your activities by adding the `android:parentActivityName` attribute to each  element in your app manifest file
2. create an instance of `TaskStackBuilder` and call `addNextIntentWithParentStack()`, passing it the Intent for the activity you want to start.

For more details see [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide any information of what you've tried, so i'll give you the simplest answer:

method `startActivity(Intent intent)`, more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).

---

Edit: Hmm, how about this? I don't have SDK around me now, but i can provide a concept. I'm not sure if it works, but i hope it'll guide you to soultion.

Let's imagine this is ActivityA's code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (doINeedActivityB) {
        Intent activityC = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        this.startActivity(activityA);
    }
    if (doINeedActivityC) {
        Intent activityC = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        this.startActivity(activityC);
    }
}
```

Comment: edited. But, even without my insufficient information provided, your reply doesn't say anything about opening of multiple acitivies. Hope the edit, helps